# What is the use of this sharp edge found on the leading edge of a DA 40NG wing?

Tags: aircraft-design, aerodynamics, wing

[image]

It is found on both wings and there is also another long one near the wing root too.

Answer (score 3):

I'm leaving the aerodynamics to someone who paid more attention in classes but, as I remember, that leading edge is supposed to induce flow separation at lower angles of attack (for that portion of the wing), inducing a small buffet into the ailerons and a buffet feed-back to the pilot through the control stick.

Without it, the wing would begin separation (and stalling) at the root, and by the time you get the buffet in the stick the whole wing is basically already stalled.

Comment: [Stall strip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stall_strips). But shouldn't it be located [near the root](http://www.boldmethod.com/learn-to-fly/aircraft-systems/stall-strips/) rather than near the tip.

Comment: there is a larger one near the root (as you want the root to stall first), also a small one along the ailerons to produce buffet

Comment: It's actually the correct answer! If the Angle of Attack rises to much then this little edge will produce turbulent air which hits the elevator and produces notable feedback in the pilots control stick.